# Access Lotus Domino object from asp.net mvc, get session is not initialized error, any idea?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lotus-domino, lotus

in my asp.net mvc 4 web apps in VS2012, I need to access Lotus Domino data, I followed this example  to implement it:
 
 I inserted Inerop.Domino by Nugut, and I have Lotus client and designer in my workstation. 
 this is my codes tried to get the Domino object, the codes are compiled succcessfully, but when I  run it I got error, this is my codes:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Domino;

namespace FINmvc.Controllers
{
    public class FINController : Controller
     {
    private NotesSession _lotusNotesSession = null;
    private NotesDatabase _lotusDatabase = null;
    private NotesView _noteview = null;
    //
    // GET: /Travel/

    public ActionResult Index(
    {
        _lotusNotesSession = new Domino.NotesSession(); //it seems the session is null here
        _lotusDatabase = _lotusNotesSession.GetDatabase("ProdServer","apps/telephon.nsf",false);
        // I got error here: "Session has not been initialized", 

        return View(db.FINtravels.ToList());
    }
  ....
```

I appreciate if anybody can help me out. thanks a lot,

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new instance of a `NotesSession` object, but it would appear that you need to explicitly initialize it as well.  Note a few statements in [the documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESSESSION_CLASS.html):

> - To access the current session from a NotesDatabase object, use the Parent property in NotesDatabase.
> - To access the current session through COM, see "Creating a session object" and "Initializing a session."Examples
> - To access the current session through OLE, see "Using OLE."

If you need to initialize a session, take a look at their [examples](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ACCESSING_THE_DOMINO_OBJECTS_THROUGH_COM_INITIALIZING.html).  Specifically, it looks like the `NotesSession` object exposes a couple of methods for initialization:

```
session.Initialize("passwordOptional")
```

and

```
session.InitializeUsingNotesUserName("name", "passwordOptional")
```

So in your code you'd need to create the instance, then initialize it, then use it.  Something like this:

```
_lotusNotesSession = new Domino.NotesSession();
_lotusNotesSession.InitializeUsingNotesUserName("name", "passwordOptional");
_lotusDatabase = _lotusNotesSession.GetDatabase("ProdServer","apps/telephon.nsf",false);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, in my case, it is not  server, so I have to use initialize(my notes id), and I tried it, your solution is working perfectly, thank you so much.

Comment: Since it worked perfectly, it would be courteous to upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: But, I tried it today, it was working two days, today, it does not work any more, there are nothing changd in my environment.  the website are hanging tooooo long time without opening, the code stopped on line of code: _lotusNotesSession = new Domino.NotesSession();
, no compile time error, this is run time without any error message, but the site can not opened. any idea?